# noty window size different in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, noty

I want to resize the 'noty' window which is displayed when the form is submitted - make the text font and window size larger.

The 'noty' code looks like this:

```
<script>
  $(function()
    {
        $('#task-form').submit(function()
        {
            $(this).find('.submit').val('Saving...');
            $.post('biomed/default/save', $('#task-form').serialize(), function(data)
            {
                if (data.isValid)
                {
                    $(".btn").attr("disabled", true);
                    noty
                    ({
                            layout:'center',
                            text:'Your task #'+data.timestamp+' has been submitted. Redirecting... ',
                            type:'success'
                    });
                    setTimeout(function() {window.location = "biomed/progress?task_id="+data.timestamp; }, 5000);                    
                }
            ....
        ....
    ....
....
</script>
```

To change the appearance of the noty message I edited two files:

First, I have increased the width in file for the center layout media/noty/layouts/center.js:

```
container: {
     object: '<ul id="noty_center_layout_container" />',
     selector: 'ul#noty_center_layout_container',
     style: function() {
           $(this).css({
               width: '800px', <- HERE

     ....
```

and

```
            css: {
                    display: 'none',
                    width: '800px'   <- HERE
            },
```

Second, I have corrected the font in media/noty/themes/default.js:

```
      switch (this.options.layout.name) {
           case 'topCenter': case 'center': case 'bottomCenter': case 'inline':
                 this.$bar.css({
                       borderRadius: '5px',
                       border: '1px solid #eee',
                       boxShadow: "0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)"
                 });
    HERE ->      this.$message.css({fontSize: '32px', lineHeight: '40px', textAlign: 'center'});
           break;
```

The Result: this works in Firefox, but not in Chome, i.e. I now see a large windows with large readable font when submitting in Firefox, and see the default tiny font when submitting in Chrome.

Please suggest a workaround, i.e. I want it to work the same way in both browsers.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I know what happened - google-chrome took noty settings from its own (google-chrome's) local cache. That's why my manipulations with files on the server never made any changes in the Chrome browser. Cleaning the cache (History -> clear -> Cached data) worked for me - now I can see changes made to my site.